# Split the String by \ which contains following string "abc\u12345. "

Tags: java, unicode, split

Before posting I tried using string split("\u") or \\u or \u it does not work, reason being is that \u is considered as unicode character while in this case it's not.

Comment: But `'\'` and `'u'` are **not single characters here**. `\u12345` is a **single charactedr**. It is used to "escape".

Comment: It is a Unicode char. Atleast Java will use it as an Unicode character

Comment: The string literal `"abc\u12345”` is the escaped version of `"abcሴ5"`, ie the 5 characters `'a'` (U+0061) `'b'` (U+0062) `'c'` (U+0063) `'ሴ'` (U+1234) `'5'` (U+0035). So you can't use `split("\u")` or `split("\\u")`, as such characters don't actually exist in the string.  `split("\u1234")` or `split("ሴ")` would work, though. If the string contained the actual characters `'\'` (U+005C) `'u'` (U+0075) instead of `'ሴ'`, then `split("\\u")` would work.

Answer (score 2):

as already mentioned \u12345 is a unicode character and therefore handled as a single symbol. 
If you have these in your string its already too late. If you get this from a file or over network you could read your input and escape each \ or \u you encounter before storing it in your string variable and working on it.

if you elaborate the context of your task a little more, perhaps we could find other solutions for you.

Answer (score 2):

Java understands it as Unicode Character so, right thing to do will be to update the source to read it properly and avoid passing Unicode to java if not needed. 
One workaround way could be to convert the entire string into a character Array and check if character is greater than 128 and if yes, I append the rest of the array in a seperate StringBuilder. See of it below helps :

```
public static void tryMee(String input)
{
    StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b2 = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isUni = false;

    for (char c : input.toCharArray())
    {
        if (c >= 128)
        {
            b2.append("\\u").append(String.format("%04X", (int) c));
            isUni = true;
        }
        else if(isUni) b2.append(c);
        else b1.append(c);
    }   

    System.out.println("B1: "+b1);
    System.out.println("B2: "+b2);
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you can, please accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You did not escape properly

```
split("\\\\u")
```

or

```
split(Pattern.quote("\\u"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {

    public static void main (String[]args){
        String str = "abc\u12345";
        // first replace \\u with something else, for example with -u
        char [] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c: chars){
            if(c >= 128){
                sb.append("-u").append(Integer.toHexString(c | 0x10000).substring(1) ); 
            }else{
                sb.append(c);
            }  
        }
        String replaced = sb.toString();

        // now you can split by -u
        String [] splited =  sb.toString().split("-u");
        System.out.println(replaced);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
    }    
}
```